# How to integrate $\frac{2x+5}{x-1}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

I want to know how to integrate a fraction where top and bottom are of the linear form $ax+b$, such as $\frac{2x+5}{x-1}$.

I know to do integration where we have linear form at the top and polynomial degree  at the bottom.

Thanks

Comment: When the degree of the top is greater than or equal to the degree of the bottom, first do long division.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Use that

$$\frac{2x+5}{x-1}=\frac{2x-2+7}{x-1}=\frac{2(x-1)}{x-1}+\frac{7}{x-1}=2+\frac{7}{x-1}$$

Comment: Oh, thanks. It's simple once you know how to do it. Appreciated.

Comment: @LongNguyen Yes of course! You only need to become familiar with these kind of simple manipulation.

Comment: @LongNguyen Actually, even if you're not familiar with this method of manipulation, a more "naive" approach of attempting a substitution like $u=x-1$ would have done the trick. Don't be afraid to try new things.